# Error during thiinkorswim installation

Tags: apt, software-installation, java

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to install the thinkorswim application. The process involves installing the Zulu OpenJDK, which begins with importing the Azul public key and then installing the Azul package to the APT repository.

Both of these process fail with the following error:
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.

Is this just a failure with the version of Ubuntu that I am using? Is the fault really in the package archive or is the missing Release file on my system?
The apt-secure(8) states that I could override the error by altering the APT configuration to permit unsigned package installations. I would prefer not doing that.

Do you have any valid solutions to this problem? Who manages the Package archive?
Is the missing file on the package archive or on my system?

Comment: Have you verified that the version of Ubuntu you are using uses that version of the software? It is not on your system it clearly says it is missing from the repo. The package as with all packages are managed by the maker of the app. You asked the last question twice.

Answer (score 0):

The Open JDK runtime will also work for this package:

1. Open Terminal
2. Update `apt`

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the JDK:

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
   ```
4. You *may* need to tell the system that you’re using Java 8:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives –config java
   ```

From here you can continue with the installation of thinkorswim:

1. Set the downloaded shell script as executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x thinkorswim_installer.sh
   ```
2. Run the installation script:

   ```
   ./thinkorswim_installer.sh
   ```
3. Grab a cup of coffee, because the installation process will take about 10 minutes.

Hope this helps